# React-native Fb ( error: no suitable constructor found for AccessToken )

Tags: react-native

Today, I got an issue with React-native in the Android platform with Fb (0.7.0) SDK.

```
error: no suitable constructor found for AccessToken(String,String,String,<null>,<null>,<null>,<null>,<null>) constructor AccessToken.AccessToken(String,String,String,Collection<String>,Collection<String>,AccessTokenSource,Date,Date,Date) is not applicable (actual and formal argument lists differ in length) constructor AccessToken.AccessToken(Parcel) is not applicable (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After spending an hour with this issues getting an amazing solution... that was just upgraded FB (version 0.8.0) SDK for react-native...

Comment: Hello, how do you upgrade the react-native-fbsdk?

Comment: There is two way, first you can remove the older version and the other way is open your package.json file and change the FB version on there  ( "react-native-fbsdk": "^0.7.0",) to  ("react-native-fbsdk": "^0.8.0",) and run npm update

Comment: Thank you man. I had some problems with graph api after upgrading to the 0.8.0 but I solved them. Thank you for the solution

Comment: Nope. I use RN fbsdk 0.8.0 already. Something else is going on that causes this issue. Wish it did fix for me. ;-\